# Vagrant port forwarding not working on Mavericks

Tags: macos, vagrant

I'm using a [vagrant Geodjango box](https://github.com/david-wilson/vagrant-geodjango-base) and port forwarding is not working for me.

On the box, I have run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost:4567` both find nothing on the host machine.

On the Vagrant box, `curl -v 'http://localhost:8000/'` gives the usual:

```
<h2>Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.</h2>
```

which suggests that Django is running okay. But on the host machine, trying `curl -v 'http://localhost:8000/'` gives the following output:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8000; Connection refused
```

My Vagrantfile has the following port forwarding set up:

```
config.vm.forward_port 8000, 4567
```

Disabling the Mac's firewall does not help and stopping Apache makes no difference. I have tried running `lsof -i :8000` on the host machine and there is no output, so I figure nothing is using the port.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Ah, figured it out - there was a warning about port forwarding that I hadn't seen, right at the beginning of the `vagrant reload` process. Vagrant had reassigned the ports, so the site was actually running on port 2201 and `http://localhost:2201/` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good to see you figured it out yourself.

Just want to add my 2 cents, in V2 Vagrantfile, the port forwarding code block is like below, try to use the new ones so as to avoid port conflicts (back in v1 I always got confused which is which).

`config.vm.forward_port 8000, 4567` is forwarding guest port 8000 to host 4567, not the other way around.

In V2 format, it looks like below, which is clearer from my opinion

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on Yosemite and none of the ports were forwarding. Disabling the Firewall filter on the guest machine helped:

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

Comment: I can also confirm that disabling the firewall on my guest fixed the same issue for me on Yosemite

Comment: My issue was also the firewall however I wasn't using "sudo service." The documentation here is very useful https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables - pay close attention to # iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT and # iptables -F. It's worth a read even if you can use "sudo service iptables stop" because you don't want to disable firewalls without understanding the consequences.